# R & Gephi: edges in a network are not properly imported using the rgexf package

Tags: r, data-visualization, gephi

I have a problem with the R package `"rgexf"`. In particular, I have a problem with the *edges* of the network I import to Gephi. In R I can produce a database of vertices

```
>vertices
   Id Label
1   1     1
2   2     2
3   3     3
4   4     4
5   5     5
6   6     6
7   7     7
8   8     8
9   9     9
10 10    10
```

and a database of edges (a single edge to be precise)

```
>edges 
      Source Target
    1      5      9
```

I create a .gexf file using

```
  >write.gexf(output = path_gexf, nodes = vertices, edges = edges,  defaultedgetype = "undirected")
```

where `path_gexf` is just the path of the output file (which is called example.gexf).
I open example.gexf  using Gephi (version 0.8.2 beta). 
In image 1:
[image]

you can see the import report in Gephi: the number of vertices and edges is correct; I manually change the graph type to undirected and I import all data to the Data Laboratory window.

1. **Question 1**. **Why am I supposed to specify "undirected" in the import report window if I already did it in the write.gexf function?**

In image2

[image]

you can see that, after the import, the type of graph switches automatically to "directed" and **no edge is actually imported.**

In image 3

[image]

we have the list of vertices: all is fine. Labels and Id's are correctly imported. In image 4

[image]

you can see the Data Laboratory window for edges: no edge is imported, as already noted in image 2. I really do not understand why no edge is imported.

2. **Question 2. How to correct the import of the example.gexf file? At the level of R code all is smooth, and vertices / edges are correctly generated by my code. Problems occur with Gephi.**

Remarks: I have plenty of .gexf files with issues regarding the import of edges; in many cases only few edges are imported with uncorrect "Source" and "Target". Strangely enough, parallel edges are always properly counted according to their multiplicities.

I apologize for the long post.

**EDIT: some tests with dummy R code**

I did some tests using @James Tobin's code (thanks!). It works fine also on my pc. 
I did tests with graphs with 2 edges: the tests were all ok.
Then I moved to the 3,4 edges cases, using

```
require(rgexf)
vertices <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1,10),seq(1,10)))
colnames(vertices) <- c('Id','Label')
edges <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(5,1,2),c(1,1,3)))
colnames(edges) <- c('Source','Target')
write.gexf(nodes=vertices,edges=edges,
           defaultedgetype = "undirected")
```

and

```
require(rgexf)
vertices <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1,10),seq(1,10)))
colnames(vertices) <- c('Id','Label')
edges <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(5,1,4,2),c(2,3,1,2)))
colnames(edges) <- c('Source','Target')
write.gexf(nodes=vertices,edges=edges,
           defaultedgetype = "undirected")
```

In both cases the XLM code is correct w.r.t. the nodes & edges id's, labels, sources and targets.

Where are the issues? In the 3 edges case the import report in Gephi is correct, while the data laboratory edge window does not show the edge

```
<edge id="1" source="1" target="1" weight="1.0"/>
```

In the 4 edges case the edge

```
 <edge id="0" source="5" target="2" weight="1.0"/>
```

is missing, instead.

I start to believe there is a bug in Gephi 0.8.2 and not in my code.

Any suggestion/comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: Even though you already specified the graph as undirected in the gexf file, directed is the default, although clicking it is a little bit annoying, at least its not that big of deal. From a safety perspective, its easier to allow a user to double check what kind of graph they are importing than to potentially select incorrectly. It takes 2 seconds, not that big of a deal.

Question 2: I copied your example

```
require(rgexf)
vertices <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1,10),seq(1,10)))
colnames(vertices) <- c('Id','Label')
edges <- as.data.frame(cbind(5,9))
colnames(edges) <- c('Source','Target')
write.gexf(output='testgex.gexf',nodes=vertices,edges=edges,
          defaultedgetype = "undirected")
```

but I don't have any issues with edges.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Perhaps you can include your exact code that fails? Perhaps your edges aren't in data.frame form? Just guessing because I couldn't replicate your error.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I checked your code and I arrived at the same results. I suspect there is some hidden problem in my code, then. I will begin with checking the data.frame form, as you suggested :-)

Comment: You just found a bug! I have added it to the issues list in the package repo https://bitbucket.org/gvegayon/rgexf/issue/17/if-no-dynamic-graph-defaultedgetype-is-not Have a lot of pending things to do here! I'll try to get it by the weekend. Thanks! (George Vega, author of rgexf)

Comment: Thank you George for the rgexf package and your comment! One question: is it possible to visualize the full (Java?) code of the result of a write.gexf command? Maybe I can find where the import fails...

Comment: I meant XLM, not Java.

Comment: `capture.output(print(gexf))` ... should give you the XML that was generated... you can then write this to a file for inspection.